# Columnwise multiple summarizes using ddply

Tags: r, multiple-columns, plyr, data-manipulation

I have time series data with many columns. Now I want to summarize them using ddply. I want result in a way that I will get mean of some of the columns and sum for othercolumns in a same data frame.
Can anyone suggest how can I do?
I came so far  upto this for this data [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c3h9zix1hcrtf50/testdata.csv).

```
ddply(test,.(Date = format(Date,"%Y-%b")), colwise(mean,.(X1, x2))) .
```

I want to get sum of x3 and x4 column in the same dataframe. Can anyone suggest how can i do that?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.